# Confidence interval of coefficients using Generalized Estimating Equation (GEE)

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am running the linear regression models using generalized estimating equation with geepack. The `confint(fit)` command does not seem to work in here. For example:

```
f2 <- geeglm(FEV1 ~ Age, data = Hospdata, family=gaussian, id=HHID)  
summary(f2)
confint(f2)
```

I get the following error message in running `confint(f2)`:

```
> confint(f2)
Waiting for profiling to be done...
Error in `[.data.frame`(summ$coefficients, , "Std. Error", drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected
```

Is there any way to find the confidence interval in here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(geepack)
data(dietox)
dietox$Cu     <- as.factor(dietox$Cu)
mf1 <- formula(Weight~Cu*poly(Time,3))
gee1 <- geeglm(mf1, data=dietox, id=Pig,
               family=poisson("identity"),corstr="ar1")
cc <- coef(summary(gee1))
citab <- with(as.data.frame(cc),
     cbind(lwr=Estimate-1.96*Std.err,
           upr=Estimate+1.96*Std.err))
rownames(citab) <- rownames(cc)
```

For convenience, you could write a `confint` method that encapsulates this:

```
confint.geeglm <- function(object, parm, level = 0.95, ...) {
    cc <- coef(summary(object))
    mult <- qnorm((1+level)/2)
    citab <- with(as.data.frame(cc),
                  cbind(lwr=Estimate-mult*Std.err,
                        upr=Estimate+mult*Std.err))
    rownames(citab) <- rownames(cc)
    citab[parm,]
}

confint(gee1)
```

Comment: Thanks - if I understand correctly, this relies on the assumption of a Gaussian (normal) distribution of the estimate. May I ask you to confirm that this is indeed the case, possibly with a reference? This would help me a lot to actually use it for my research analysis.

Comment: yes, that's a Wald confidence interval (assumes normal sampling distribution of the estimate)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the really fast answer and directing me to the Wald confidence intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Simply `broom:tidy(f2, conf.int = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

`confint` is from the stats package. `geeglm` is from the geepack package.

You need to determine where the confident intervals are stored in the model output.

Use `str(f2)` or derive them from `summary(f2)`.

Also have a look at `f2$` and tab to auto-complete through the model objects.

Also, also - look in the documentation - [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geepack/geepack.pdf). You may have to construct your own as the example model I ran did not generate CIs. You may have to hand roll them from parameter standard errors.

Answer (score 0):

It's four years on and I arrived here for the same reason.  For the benefit of others who also arrive here, after seeing Ben's reply above, I realised that the confint() function computes profile likelihood intervals.  It won't work with a GEE, because it isn't based on a likelihood.

The base function confint.default() gives Wald intervals and can be used with a GEE.  It should give the same results as Ben's function above.

Answer (score 0):

You need the geeasy package installed and loaded

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35047337)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).