# How to calculate a confidence interval for "geese" object

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I would like to know how to compute a confidence interval for a "geese" object, the regression output for an ordinal generalized estimating equation. This type of object is not accepted by tidy() or conf.int().

See the reproducible example below.

```
n2 <- 3
n1 <- 7
data <- data.frame(id= c("101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110",
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110"),
exposure= c("group1", "group3", "group6", "group2", "group4", "group5", "group1", "group3", "group6", "group2",
"group4", "group5", "group7", "group7", "group1", "group3", "group4", "group5", "group7", "group7",
"group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", 
"group6", "group2","group6", "group2" , "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2","group6", "group2",  
"group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2", "group6", "group2"),
outcome=c("1", "2", "3", "2", "1", "3", "1", "1", "2", "3",
"1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1",
"1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1",
"1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1",
"1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1", "3", "1", "1"))

data$outcome <- factor(data$outcome, ordered = TRUE)

data <- data %>%
arrange(id)

model1 <- ordgee(outcome ~  exposure,
id = id,
data = data,
corstr= "independence")

summary(model1)
```

I tried to use conf.int(), tidy() and they do not accept a "geese" object.

I also tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221280/confidence-interval-of-coefficients-using-generalized-estimating-equation-gee)

But I got an error when I ran that.

Answer (score 0):

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221280/confidence-interval-of-coefficients-using-generalized-estimating-equation-gee), which works for `geeglm` fits, but extracting the necessary guts from `summary.geese`. The only obscure part is

> `std.err`: Type of standard error to be calculated. Def[au]lt 'san.se' is
> the usual robust estimate.  Other options are 'jack': if
> approximate jackknife variance estimate should be computed.
> 'j1s': if 1-step jackknife variance estimate should be
> computed.  'fij': logical indicating if fully iterated
> jackknife variance estimate should be computed.

```r
coef.geese <- function(object) object$beta
vcov.geese <- function(object, std.err = "san.se") { 
  covmat <- switch(std.err, 
    jack = {
        object$vbeta.ajs
    }, 
    j1s = {
        object$vbeta.j1s
    }, 
    fij = {
        object$vbeta.fij
    }, 
    object$vbeta)
    nm <- names(coef(object))
    dimnames(covmat) <- list(nm, nm)
  covmat
}
```

Once we've defined `coef()` and `vcov()` methods, `stats::confint.default()` just works (`confint.default(model1)`). The results in this case are ridiculously wide, but I think (????) that's because this is a tiny/overparameterized example ... ??

Please double-check these results against an alternative approach to see that they make sense ...